# What's the Sunnah number of sending blessings to the prophet (ﷺ) daily?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, ibadah

How much is the prescribed amount of sending blessings to the prophet (ﷺ) daily according to sound ahadeeth?

Comment: What is Salat-an-Nabawiyah?

Comment: I wonder if there was anybody making statics at the time. Ahadith cover a whole bunch of raka'as and they show that the prophet used to vary them.

Comment: Crimson Salat An-Nabawiya means doing prayer in the manner the Prophet of Allah (ﷺ) did it, but when I first posted this I made a mistake and thought that it meant sending blessings to the prophet (ﷺ) (اللهم صلِ وسلم على نبييُنا محمد)